# Не могу получить элемент через id

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google-maps

Есть у меня контент для инфо окна маркера:

```
var contentString = '<div id="infowindow_content">'
                + '<p><h5>' + order.description + '</h5>'
                + '<p><strong>Address:</strong> '+order.address+'<br>Customer:<strong><a href="/'+order.user+'"> '+order.user+'</a></strong><strong><a style="float:right;" href="/order?id='+order.id+'">Order page</a></strong><div id="callButton"><p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="presenter('+i+'); return false;">Call</button></div></div>';
```

Но икак не могу достучатся к элементу "CallButton". При віполнении

```
document.getElementById('callButton');
```

Возникает ошибка

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>   Подскажите почему не видно этот элемент?

Comment: Предоставьте результирующий HTML код. Проблема очевидно в нем. Посмотреть код в современных браузерах можно с помощью Ctrl+U или используйте панель разработчика.

Comment: А в какой момент вызывается `document.getElementById('callButton');` ? После создания и выведения на экран содержимого `contentString ` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  спасибо! Я просто вызывал функцию перед тем как отобразить инфо окно.